# static_assert<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "") fails because of unused template types

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, type-traits

I am making a templated `Matrix` class, and I have limited the template parameters to the *integral* and *floating* point data types by

```
template class Matrix<int>;
template class Matrix<float>; ..etc
```

I was implementing a `random()` static member function, and to make it uniform random distribution from `0.0` to `1.0`, I used the `std::is_floating_point<T>` to limit the use of templates of *floating* point types. and I thought that the `static_assert` will fire if only `T` is not a floating point type, but the assertion fails for every `template class Matrix<T>;` where T is an *integral* type.

When I comment out all *integral* types, it works fine, but I can't do this as I need to be able to make `Matrix<T>` instances with `T` is an *integral* type. How would I fix it?

Note that I have provided the `template class Matrix<T>` for every *integral*/*floating*-point type because I get the `undefined reference` error. So I limit the initialization to the *integral* and *floating* point types.

```
// Matrix.cpp
template<typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::rand(const size_t& r, const size_t& c) {
    Matrix<T> result{ r, c };
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
        "result_type must be a floating point type");
    const float range_from = 0.0;
    const float range_to = 1.0;
    std::random_device                  rand_dev;
    std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T>   distr(range_from, range_to);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            result[i][j] = distr(generator);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
//...
template class Matrix<int>;
template class Matrix<long>;
template class Matrix<float>;
template class Matrix<double>;
```

Comment: You need SFINAE (or `requires` of C++20) or specialization if you explicitly instantiate the class (and so all its (non template) methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several choices:

- provide (template) code in header instead of cpp (see [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file))
- explicitly instantiate methods instead of class:

  ```
  // all individual available methods of the class
  template Matrix<int> Matrix<int>::other_method(/*..*/); 
  // ...

  // Whole class
  template class Matrix<float>;
  template class Matrix<double>;
  ```
- Use SFINAE:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  class Matrix
  {
      template <typename U = T,
                std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, U>::value
                                 && std::is_floating_point<U>::value, int> = 0>
      Matrix<T> rand(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);
  // ...
  };
  ```
- or `requires` from C++20:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  class Matrix
  {
      Matrix<T> rand(const size_t &r, const size_t &c) requires (std::is_floating_point<T>::value);
  // ...
  };
  ```
- or specialize the class

  ```
  template<typename T, typename Enabler = void>
  class Matrix
  {
  // ...
  };

  template<typename T>
  class Matrix<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>
  {
      Matrix<T> rand(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);
  // ...
  };
  ```

Answer (score 2):

> When I comment out all *integral type*s, it works fine, but I can't do
>   this as I need to be able to make `Matrix<T>` instances with `T` is an
>   *integral typ*e. How would I fix it?

As *@Jarod42* pointed out in the comments, you could apply the *[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)* to restrict the use of `rand()` function if and only if the template type is a floating point.

Bonus remark: The same technique can be applied to restrict the instantiation of the class `Matrix<T>`, by instantiating the class conditionally for the allowed types mentioned in the traits.

Following is an example code(compiles with [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) which demonstrates the idea.

### ([See online](https://godbolt.org/z/oOO7uF))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> // for std::conjunction, std::negation, std::is_arithmetic, std::is_floating_point, std::enable_if

// traits for filtering out the allowed types
template<typename Type>
using is_allowed = std::conjunction<
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>,    // is equal to  std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>>
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, bool>>,    // negate the types which shouldn't be compiled
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, char>>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, char16_t>>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, char32_t>>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, wchar_t>>
>;

template<typename Type, typename ReType = void>
using is_allowed_type = std::enable_if_t<is_allowed<Type>::value, ReType>;

template<typename Type, typename Enable = void> class Matrix;
// conditional instantiation of the template class
template<typename Type> class Matrix<Type, is_allowed_type<Type>> /* final */
{
public:
    template<typename T = Type>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, Matrix<T>> rand(const size_t& r, const size_t& c)
   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SFINAE to restrict the use of rand()
    {
        Matrix<T> result{/*args*/};
        // other code
        return result;
    }
};
template class Matrix<int>;
template class Matrix<long>;
template class Matrix<float>;

int main()
{
   Matrix<double> obj;
   obj.rand(1, 2);
}
```